# Changing the default operation of "F5" (for the way that "SHIFT+F5" works) on MS PowerPoint

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-powerpoint

I would love to change the default operation of my PowerPoint so I can press <kbd>F5</kbd> and go to the full screen mode with the current slide.

Yes, I know that I can do that with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>, but I want to get the same functionality that <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> provides with just <kbd>F5</kbd>. I use it a lot of times each day and almost never use the "start from the first one" shortcut.

I need to do it on PowerPoint 2003 and 2007.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [AutoHotkey](http://autohotkey.com) to map <kbd>F5</kbd> to <kbd>Shift</kbd>**+**<kbd>F5</kbd> inside Microsoft PowerPoint only.

- **PowerPoint 2003**:

  ```
  #IfWinActive ahk_class PP11FrameClass
      F5::SendInput, +{F5}
  #IfWinActive
  ```
- **PowerPoint 2007**:

  ```
  #IfWinActive ahk_class PP12FrameClass
      F5::SendInput, +{F5}
  #IfWinActive
  ```
- **PowerPoint 2010**:

  ```
  #IfWinActive ahk_class PPTFrameClass
      F5::SendInput, +{F5}
  #IfWinActive
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Microsoft did not include a Key Bindings option with MS Powerpoint so there is no "official" way to change the bindings that I know of.

A possible alternative solution would be to map your <kbd>F5</kbd>  key to always act like <kbd>Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>F5</kbd> .

There is a guide to do so [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/map-any-key-to-any-key-on-windows-xp-vista/)